# Android Sql Lite download from sql server using webservice

Tags: android, asp.net, sql-server, sqlite, android-webservice

I have a website which display quotes grouped by author.
The front end is in asp.net and the database is in sql server 2012.

The table is simple with four fields.
Id numeric and primary key
Author nvarchar 
Quote nvarchar 
Insertdate datetime.

Now, I want to create a mobile app on both Android and ios platform.

First I started with Android using android studio.

I have the basic design ready with layout.

Now, I am stuck with the main requirements which is I want to give user the options of downloading the quotes when online and the quotes already downloaded should be available offline.

I have been trying multiple tutorial but can't find the one with the  exact requirements.

So, is this the below right way of going forward?

I created a webservice and transferring the data using retrofit library. Now I'm able to display the data but not storing it locally. As this part is complete just want to be sure if I have done it the correct way as don't want to rollback once I start working on the part two that is storing the data in sqlite.

Also, can I reuse some of the functionality on ios.

Answer (score 0):

Seems reasonable.

What you probably want to do now is introduce local storage for the data so they don't have to be online and accessing the API all the time. For Android SQLite is the normal way of storing data, and iOS uses Core Data (although SQLite is available).

Everything up to the API is reusable, you'll need to develop the download and storage for each ecosystem separately.

NB - that being said, I believe that Google's Firebase cloud database has an offline mode, so you could potentially work around the need to develop the syncs separately and use Firebase's SDK to get the data into an auto synced local store. Haven't used it myself, but it;s out there.